# communicate between localhosts using signalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am implementing singalR in .net core. I have 2 projects, one to send notification and other to display notification alert. When I send message from sender application, then it should display a notification in receiver application. how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Krunal

I have googled and tried with below code in sender application hub but when it executes this line "connection.Start().Wait()".

```
var connection = new HubConnection("https://localhost:portnumer/"); // this is the receiver application localhost url
IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("chatHub");
connection.Start().Wait();
await myHub.Invoke("chatHub", "Hello World");
```

it gives error in console "Error: An unexpected error occurred invoking 'SendMessage' on the server." which is in button click js code.

```
document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Is your hub connection being established correctly? That code you posted seems like an AspNet connection, not AspNet Core.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using is for AspNet.

For AspNet Core you should add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` NuGet package and use the `HubConnectionBuilder` method:

```cs
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                  .WithUrl("https://localhost:portnumer/chatHub")
                  .Build();

connection.StartAsync().ContinueWith((t) => {
    connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "Hello World!");
}).Wait();
```

In order to get the message sent by the method `SendMessage`, you need to subscribe to it in your client application (JavaScript).

```js
connection.on("SendMessage", (message) => {
  // Do something with {message}
});
```

Comment: I have tried with above code it went successfully in sender application but the break point doesn't come to receiver application's chatHub 'SendMessage' action and so it doesn't pass to "ReceiveMessage" method in chat.js.

Comment: Invoke sends messages. For you to receive a message you would have to do connection.on("SendMessage", ... as explained in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)